Is any mapper utility in a customized angular js to generate xslt 3.0?
Requirement: To integrate a mapper utility in a customized angular js dashbaord where user can implement their map and can generate xslt 3.0 which will be deployed in Saxonica engine.
Is any mapper utility available to fulfil the requirement...?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

What do you want to process with XSLT 3.0/Saxon, XML input? Or JSON input?

its very vague, you want to generate XSLT code based on some mapping specification?
can you show what an example specification looks like?
P.S. I suspect using XQuery would be much simpler. (but I know of no mapper in either case)
